# Что в этом куске кода делается?

Tags: java

```
public String getPath() {
    final StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    AStarNode p = this;
    while (p.direction != 'X') {
        path.insert(0, p.direction);
        p = p.previous;
    }
    return path.toString();
}
```

Взято с http://www.brian-borowski.com/software/puzzle/AStarNode.java

Comment: Собирается строковое описание найденного пути

Comment: Выводится путь ноды?

Comment: Что за нод? Наибольший общий делитель?

Comment: нод = node. в переводе  - узел.

Comment: а что значит : path.insert(0, p.direction); ?

Comment: вставить в начало пути направление на текущий узел.

Answer (score 1):

Данный метод возвращает путь от начального узла до текущего текущего узла. Указанный класс - это узел для реализации алгоритма нахождения путь A*.